# how to model AWGN for a Triangular waveform

Tags: power, noise, signal-to-noise, snr

If I want to generate some Additive White Gaussian Random Noise on top of my signal, how should I do it, if my waveform is triangular instead of being rectangular. 
Because I am sure I have to somehow account for this in the noise variance, but I don't know how?

Comment: expand on your frequency domains and purpose.

Comment: Did you want this for BER simulation? using SNR or a multiple of std.dev?

Comment: Would you like to look at correlation on 2nd harmonic output? or ratio of signal to noise (p-p)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 yes, I need it for BER simulation

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75. No I just need it for signal to noise (p-p).... Not interested for second harmonic

Comment: Std Deviation of noise depends on time duration relative to repeated triangle cycles This can be computed if I knew what you are looking for. Otherwise using RMS ratio of each from spectral density on a spectrum analyzer

Answer (score 0):

Here is triangle-wave with 10db SNR random noise superimposed. The signal frequency is 1MHz; the noise bandwidth is 50MHz (set by the sample-spacing used to generate the waveform).

The lower waveform shows the output of a 3MHz L+C 2-pole low-pass-filter

[image]